# Выборка по части поля таблицы SQLite

Tags: android

Создал функцию, которая выбирает записи из таблицы в случае если данная строка включена в состав поля DATETIME. Поле хранит дату в форму "yyyy-mm-dd HH:ss". Мне нужна выборка только по "yyyy-mm-dd". (COL_3 - это DATETIME).

```
public Cursor getDayData(String calendarDate) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    COL_1,
                    COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5}, COL_3 + " LIKE '%"+ calendarDate + "%'",
            null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Пример **calendarDate**: 2017-11-24.
В активности имеется вот такой код:

```
dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
dbHelper.getDayData(dateDBstring);

String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.nameLW, R.id.datetimeLW, R.id.descriptionLW};
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);

listDoDay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDoDay);
listDoDay.setAdapter(adapter);
listDoDay.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptylistDay));

dbHelper.close();
```

Такой же код я использую в другой активности и он работает

Comment: Если у вас calendarDate будет = 2017-11-24, она разве не выведет, все данные с этой датой? С такой выборкой, как у вас.

Comment: Проблема решена. Нужно было присвоить курсору вызов функции из БД. cursor = dbHelper.getDayData(dateDBstring). И в другой активности это было))